# Conditionally appending to a list in Elixir?

Tags: list, append, elixir

I'm working on Elixir code after a few months on Python, and my memory of idiomatic Elixir is fuzzy.

This code works:

```elixir
# Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
children = [
  # Start the Ecto repository
  supervisor(Ssauction.Repo, []),
  # Start the endpoint when the application starts
  supervisor(SsauctionWeb.Endpoint, []),

  supervisor(Absinthe.Subscription, [SsauctionWeb.Endpoint]),
]

children
= if System.get_env("PERIODIC_CHECK") == "ON" do
    Enum.concat(children, [worker(Ssauction.PeriodicCheck, [])])
  else
    children
  end
```

But I'm sure it's awkward. How would one rewrite this idiomatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a helper function that accepts a conditional:

```elixir
defp append_if(list, condition, item) do
  if condition, do: list ++ [item], else: list
end
```

And then use it like this:

```elixir
[1,2,3]
|> append_if(true, 4)
|> append_if(false, 1000)
```

Produces:

```elixir
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It looks like you are using the [`Supervisor.Spec`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html) module, which is deprecated. You can define your supervision tree in a more modern way something like this:

```elixir
children =
  [
    Ssauction.Repo,
    SsauctionWeb.Endpoint,
    {Absinthe.Subscription, [SsauctionWeb.Endpoint]}
  ]
  |> append_if(System.get_env("PERIODIC_CHECK") == "ON", Ssauction.PeriodicCheck)
```

Although you'll probably need to modify your child supervisors to implement the  [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html) behaviour.

---

If you are going to build up large lists, it's common to prepend to the list and then do a single reverse of the results, to avoid appeding which traverses the whole list each time:

```elixir
defp prepend_if(list, condition, item) do
  if condition, do: [item | list], else: list
end

def build_list do
  []
  |> prepend_if(true, 1)
  |> prepend_if(true, 2)
  |> prepend_if(true, 3)
  |> prepend_if(false, nil)
  |> prepend_if(false, 5000)
  |> Enum.reverse()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do;

```
[
  supervisor(Ssauction.Repo, []),
  supervisor(SsauctionWeb.Endpoint, []),
  supervisor(Absinthe.Subscription, [SsauctionWeb.Endpoint]),
]
|> Kernel.++(if System.get_env("PERIODIC_CHECK") == "ON" do
   [worker(Ssauction.PeriodicCheck, [])]
  else
   []
  end
)
```